# Creating react application stucks

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, npx

I use command: `npx create-react-app final-app` and it stucked:

[image]

It was already 10 attempt and the same thing happens every time. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Is this a Windows system that you're working on?

Comment: Yes, im working on Windows 10 system.

Comment: Have you encountered any error while executing the command?

Comment: Have you encountered any error while executing the command?

Comment: No, this only stucked as you can see on the screenshot. What should i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the yarn dependencies again by command: `yarn install --force` and it fixed my problem